# Gulp process all files in directory

Tags: gulp

I have css and js files in a directory (and subdirectories). I'm looking into different tools to compress the assets in all the directories. I'm trying to find a way to get gulp to compress all the files in those directories and save the compressed file in the **same** directory and name it with the following convention: **[name].min.css** or **[name].min.js**. So **example.js** would become **example.min.js**.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I've read the following on this:

http://gulpjs.com/plugins/

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You usually don't want to generate the minified files in the same directory as the original files. You write all files that are generated by your build script to a single output directory. Some advantages of this approach are:

- Makes it easier to clean the build and recreate everything from scratch: you just delete that one output folder.
- You don't have to worry about generated files accidentally getting picked up by your build and getting processed again.

But since you asked, here's a solution that creates the minified files in the same directory as the original files. This creates a `.min.css` and `.min.js` file for every `.css` and `.js` file. All CSS files are assumed to be in a directory called `css` (or its subdirectories) and all JS files are assumed to be in a directory called `js` (or its subdirectories):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('css', function () {
  return gulp.src([
      'css/**/*.css',
      '!css/**/*.min.css',
     ])
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
      path.extname = ".min.css";
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

gulp.task('js', function () {
  return gulp.src([
      'js/**/*.js',
      '!js/**/*.min.js',
     ])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
      path.extname = ".min.js";
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js']);
```

Notice the negation pattern `!css/**/*.min.css` that is used to prevent the already minified CSS from getting minified *again* on the next build. Same for the JavaScript.

I used [gulp-cssnano](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssnano) and [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) to minify the CSS and JS, but there's plenty of other options out there that can act as drop-in replacements.

Comment: If I was to have them go to a different directory, is there a way to keep the directory structure in that other directory? So if I had `css/example/user/data.css` and I put it in a `public` directory I would want `public/example/user/data.min.css`

Comment: Keeping the directory structure is the default behavior, so you just have to replace `gulp.dest('css')` with `gulp.dest('public')`. No extra work necessary. With your destination directory now being `public`, don't forget that you can remove the negation pattern in `gulp.src()` that I used in my answer above.