# Gulp uglify - overwrite uglified files

Tags: gulp, glob

I have a gulp task to uglify my JS:

```
gulp.task('uglify', ['eslint'], () => {
  return gulp.src(jsDest + '/*.js')
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(stripDebug())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest));
});
```

It works fine, but as I am using a wildcard to identify JS files, I end up with new files named `name.min.min.js` rather than existing minified files being overwritten.

A work around I have come up with is to have an additional task which cleans out these files before I uglify again:

```
gulp.task('cleanUglified', () => {
  return del.sync('dist/js/*.min.js');
});

gulp.task('uglify', ['cleanUglified', 'eslint'], () => {
...
});
```

While this works fine, I'm sure there must be a way to have my task ignore anything named `*.min*` and in fact overwrite any that already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - I can ignore the already minified files and overwrite them by using this pattern to select the files to uglify:

<s>`return gulp.src(jsDest + '/*[^.min].js')`</s>

EDIT

Following the below comments, I have updated to:

`return gulp.src(['*.js', '!*.min.js'])`

Comment: This is wrong and doesn't do what you think it does. `[^.min]` negates all four characters `.`, `m`, `i`, `n` _individually_. This means that files with names like `main.js` (ends with `n.js`) or `zoom.js` (ends with `m.js`) will _not be minified at all_. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376614/gulp-process-all-files-in-directory/35379684#35379684) to an identical question on how to solve this correctly.